# My mongo query read run more than 5000 milliseconds

Tags: mongodb

I have a mysql as primary db and mongodb as secondary database.
I run a query on production and it run for more than 5 seconds.

Here is my query when i run with explain

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor host_1_type_1 multi",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 1,
"nscannedObjects" : 1,
"nscanned" : 313566,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 313553,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 627118,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 14,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 6555,
"indexBounds" : {
    "host" : [
        [
            "",
            {

            }
        ],
        [
            /shannisideup/i,
            /shannisideup/i
        ]
    ],
    "type" : [
        [
            "ambassador-profile",
            "ambassador-profile"
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "mongoserver:27017"
}
```

i've added an indexes

```
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "db.visitor",
    "name" : "_id_"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "host" : 1,
        "type" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "db.visitor",
    "name" : "host_1_type_1"
}
]
```

But i still don't know why is it so slow when running query

```
db.visitor.find({ host:/shannisideup/i, type:"ambassador-profile" }).limit(1)
```

FYI i run a different server for my apps and my mongodb server in AWS cloud.
For which mongodb running EC2 m3.medium, i've tried raising the openfile limit as mongodb website suggested. My mongodb is running on separate 100GB disk mounted via /dev/sdf.
I run mongodb version 2.4.5
When my mongodb runs, the CPU load almost always 100%

My MMS stat for opcounter are:

- command: 19.11
- query: 13.79
- update: 0.03
- delete: 0.00001
- getmore: 0
- insert: 0.03

My highest Pagefaults is 0.02

What can i do to optimize my mongodb to less then 1 second?

Comment: How big is the host field? Most likely the regex is having to go crazy, it should also be noted that the current order of your index is not optimal for this query. You should put exact matched fields first and then your partial matched fields

Comment: hi Sammaye, i don't know how long/big is my host field but i use string for it, my host is for saving website url. about indexes, so you would suggest that i index host first then type separately?

Comment: Nah I would make a compound index of `{type:1, host:1}` and see if that helps, since of course having the regex first means you gotta scan the whole index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll walk thru a few things that should help, although I want to make clear up front that a case insensitive regex search ("host:/shannisideup/i") cannot use an index so there are limits to what you can do with this data model and search. You can see that it's scanning a large number of objects ("nscanned" : 313566) just to return 1 document.

Things to do:

- Upgrade your instance with a faster cpu - the 100% cpu load during
  this case insensitive search is a clearly indicator that at times
  your database is cpu bound. A faster cpu will help. More memory
  (which typically comes with Amazon EC2 instances when you move to a
  faster cpu) won't hurt either. Same with a faster disk (SSD).
- Lower case your host field before storing it in MongoDB - if you
  store all your hosts in lower case and then lowercase your search
  string prior to search, you can get rid of the case-insensitive flag
  for the regex. If you can combine that with a prefix operator in your
  regex you would be able to use the index which would help.
- Consider using a dedicated text search product (like Solr or
  Elasticsearch) for the host query. MongoDB is limited in it's text
  search capabilities, particularly with regard to wild card searches.
  You may find that something like Elasticsearch or Solr may provide
  better performance.

A few links that you may find useful:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

http://selectnull.leongkui.me/2014/02/02/mongodb-elasticsearch-perfect-nosql-duo/

Comment: oh, i get it. that's why it scan full document.
Thanks for the answer, i'll optimize mongodb first and if it still cannot reach the performance i expected, i'll research solr

Comment: @IhsanKurniawan actually regex can use an index, it just has to do a full index scan. The more appropiate word is that it cannot efficiently use the index